# Ploting GEE image with imshow and adding an cartopy.io.img_tiles using add_image

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, matplotlib, array, cartopy

I transformed a GEE image in an numpy array and I'm trying to plot a this array using `plt.imshow()` with a background image of cartopy image tiles (cimgt) with `.add_image()`. However, the array and background are not matching in the final plot.

I'm using the same extetion in imshow (`x0c, x1c, y0c, y1c = ax.properties()['extent']`) and the same projection `transform=background.crs`.

I tried to change the second parameter of `.add_image`, however this just changed the image resolution.

Here is part of my code.

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.io.img_tiles as cimgt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x0 = -50.152
x1 = -50.140
y0 = -21.426
y1 = -21.419

background = cimgt.GoogleTiles(style='satellite')

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14, 5))
ax = plt.subplot(projection=background.crs)

ax.set_extent([x0, x1, y0, y1])

ax.add_image(background, 18)

x0c, x1c, y0c, y1c = ax.properties()['extent']

img = ax.imshow(array, cmap=cmap, norm=norm,
                extent=[x0c, x1c, y0c, y1c],
                transform=background.crs,
                alpha=0.35,  
                zorder=10,    
                origin='upper',
                )

plt.title('Setembro')
plt.colorbar(img)
plt.show()
```

[image: Here is the output]

Comment: I solved this problem by getting the coordinates (x0, x1, y0, y1) for ax.set_extent() in the AOI used to clip the GEE 

`image. extend = AOI.bounds().getInfo()['coordinates']`
`x0, y0 = extend[0][0]`
`x1, y1 = extend[0][2]`